# Convergence in probability of a composite function.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, continuity

Question: Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}.$ If $X_n \to X$ in probability, then $f(X_n) \to f(X)$ in probability. The result is false if $f$ is merely Borel measurable.

[Hint: Truncate $f$ at $\pm A$ for a large $A.$]

This is an exercise problem from "A Course in Probability Theory."
The $X_n,\ X$ are both random variables (measurable functions).
It would be much easier if $f$ were uniformly continuous, but I can't figure out how to solve for a just continuous function $f.$

Thank you.

Comment: Uniform continuouity of $f$ is a good point. What do you know about $f$ restricted to $[-A,A]$ for any $A>0$? What do you know about $\lim_{A\to \infty} P(X \not \in [-A,A])$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $0<A<\infty$, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[-A,A]$. Fix $\epsilon>0,\eta>0$. Then

$$
\{\omega:|f(X_n(\omega))-f(X(\omega))|>\epsilon,|X_n(\omega)|\vee|X(\omega)|\le A\}\subseteq \{\omega:|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|>\delta\}
$$

for appropriate $\delta>0$, and

$$
\mathsf{P}(|f(X_n)-f(X)|>\epsilon)\le \mathsf{P}(|X_n-X|>\delta)+\mathsf{P}(|X|>A)+\mathsf{P}(|X_n|>A).
$$

Pick $A$ s.t. $\mathsf{P}(|X|>A/2)\le \eta$. Then
$$
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathsf{P}(|f(X_n)-f(X)|>\epsilon)\le 2\eta.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although when you pick an $A$ such that $P\{ \vert X \vert > A/2 \}$ is small, you are assuming that $E(\vert X \vert) < \infty,$ correct? Could you explain in which part of the question does it explain that $X$ is an integrable function? Or is it just a convention when we talk about convergence in probability?

Comment: @nobe301 Nope. Such $A$ always exists.

Comment: But what if $\vert X \vert = \infty$ on a positive measure set? Does such an $A$ exist?

Comment: @nobe301 Usually $X$ is defined as $X:\Omega\rightarrow {\mathbb{R}}$ so that $|X|<\infty$ a.s.

Comment: Also requiring $\mathbb{E}|X|<\infty$ is too restrictive...

Comment: Thank you. That was what I was wondering. Yes, now that you say it, it is too restrictive.